# CSS grid item width larger than parent frame

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to achieve a grid item to be wider than the grid frame.
However, it seems that this is not possible with a standard way.
Any idea?

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
}

.grid-item {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you put it, the item is already wider that its grid box. There is no need to add position absolute. For better understanding of what is going on, while working on grid, it is recomended to use firefox since it help you visualize every grid line.[image]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  background-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
}

.grid-item1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.grid-item2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.grid-item3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-item1"></div>
            <div class="grid-item2"></div>
            <div class="grid-item3"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can also inspect the grid in Chrome using the small "grid" button next to the element in the "Elements" tab of dev-tools.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 70vh;
  margin: -10vh -10vw -10vh -10vw;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 10vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 10vh);
}

.c {
  grid-column: 4 / -4;
  grid-row: 4 / -4;
}

.n {
  grid-column: 4 / -4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.s {
  grid-column: 4 / -4;
  grid-row: -2 / -1;
}

.e {
  grid-column: -2 / -1;
  grid-row: 4 / -4;
}

.w {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 4 / -4;
}

.ne {
  grid-column: -2 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.se {
  grid-column: -2 / -1;
  grid-row: -2 / -1;
}

.nw {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.sw {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: -2 / -1;
}

.c,
.n,
.s,
.e,
.w,
.ne,
.nw,
.se,
.sw {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="n"></div>
    <div class="ne"></div>
    <div class="e"></div>
    <div class="se"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="sw"></div>
    <div class="w"></div>
    <div class="nw"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```